# Integrabillity of a function

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

> $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
> x^2\cdot\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2}) & \text{if } x \in ( 0,1 ),\\
> 0  & \text{if } x = 0.
> \end{cases} $$ is integrable on [ 0,1 ]?

I have tried to show that it is continuous as:

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}x^2\cdot\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2})=0$$

Also,

$$f(0)=0$$

And I showed that f is differantiable:

$$f^{\prime}(0)=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x^2\cdot\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2})}{x}=\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}x\cdot\sin(\dfrac{1}{x^2})$$

It can be proven that $f^{\prime}(0)=0$ by Squeeze Theorem. And I stuck here, I can't go on. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Continuous functions on $[0,1]$ are integrable. Why do you want to look  at differentiability?

Comment: it is integrable on $[0,1]$, because it is obviously continuous in $(0,1]$, being made up of functions that are continuous there and since $\lim_{x\to 0+}f(x)=f(0)$, as you showed. A continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is integrable. As Kavi Rama Murthy said in the previous comment, you don't need to look at differentiability.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I want to use FTC I but as you said it isn't necessary.

Comment: @lorenzo thanks a lot I understand what you mean!

Comment: @beingmathematician you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

We have the Riemann integrable theorem:a function f(x) defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is integrable if and only if f is bounded and the set of discontinuous points of f have Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: Are there any other way beside Lebesgue? Because I can't use Lebesgue

Comment: Emmmmm, actually the function in your question is defined on a compact set, bounded and continuous. It’s obviously Riemann integrable .